# Control GPIO through sysfs, mmap, or device driver on program run as non-root user?

Tags: arm, embedded-linux, gpio

I am trying to make a c program to access GPIOs on an embedded linux system which will be run by a non root user. I can already access the GPIOs through sysfs (/sys/class/gpio) and have made a simple program that used mmap (through /dev/mem/) to control the GPIOs. However to write to /sys/class/gpio/ and /dev/mem/ you must have root privileges. What would be the most "correct" or standard way to access the GPIO in a program run as a non-root user?
Writing a device driver?
 
Giving the user read/write access to /sys/class/gpio/ so the program can use sysfs?
Or Giving the user read/write access to /dev/mem/ so the program can use mmap()?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential option is to make a process  [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) by setting the `s` bit.

e.g.

`chmod +s myExectuable`

However, this has terrible security implications as the process then runs as root - with all the hazards that entails.   Only an option if you really trust the user-space app, and even then, risky.

I don't think changing the default ownership and permissions of sysfs is possible without hacking up your kernel, and even then it would be tricky: sysfs is intricately connected with object model of the the Linux Driver model.

You may have more luck with the permissions on `/dev/`.

Ultimately, the correct way of solving this problem is a kernel-mode driver - in which you can implement whatever finely grained security (or lack thereof) you wish.   Furthermore, you can implement mitigation against any potential ill-effects of allowing a user-mode application to control hardware.

Comment: Thanks, kernel module it is. Dont wanna give root access so it seems like the way to go

Comment: It actually *is* possible to change the ownership or permission of sysfs nodes - just re-tested with the status leds on an embedded box.  Of course the change will not survive reboot, or reload of the module sourcing them.

Comment: Very interesting!  How is this achieved? `chown`?

Comment: Yes, just as with an ordinary file, chown or chmod depending on what you want to change.

Answer (score 1):

Granting a custom user group access to specifically needed nodes under /sys/class/gpio is a fairly solid solution where applicable - it can be done entirely from boot scripts, needing no kernel-level programming.